# PWM'ed DC motor not running when loaded

Tags: arduino, voltage, motor, pwm

I am trying to build a robot with the Arduino Uno and the H-Bridge SN75441.

The robot has 2 1.5V rated motors. I set it up with this tuto: http://www.mlbelanger.com/arduino/ard-bot/
So the circuit is like this (I have just not plugged the Arduino Vin pin in the pin 8 of the chip):
[image]
<sub>(source: [mlbelanger.com](http://www.mlbelanger.com/wp-content/uploads/ard-bot_h-bridge.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, the H-Bridge only supports down to 4.5V for the motors. That is why I had to use a 5V power input (adapter 5v @ 1A) to power the motors, with PWM (80/255, giving a 1.5V *normally*) for regulating the power to 1.5V.

So here goes my problem. I have two cases:

- one where the motors have no load, which means that the robot is in the air. The motors run at 1.5V @ 0.26A normally.
- the second one which I have trouble with: it runs at 0.5V @ 0.145A. **So the voltage dropped as the load increased.** The robot doesnt advance and makes a kinda high-frequency noise. If I use 1.5V AA batteries connected directly to the motor, it runs well so the load is not the problem, but rather the PWM setup somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the design of the H bridge driver you may be surprised at how it behaves under load conditions. Your PWM ratio is 80/255 = 0.313 and you'd have thought the driver, powered from 5V would produce: -

Vout = 5V x 0.313 = 1.57 volts. But this won't happen. Under light loads I estimate the driver is capable of swinging up to about 4.3V and down to about 1V - this means your assumed target of 5V is in fact more like 3.3V making your real output dc voltage (due to PWM) more like 1.04 volts.

It gets worse under higher load currents. The data sheet specifies that the output can swing up to 3.6 volts and down to 1.2 volts when supplying 1 A. This means, at your specified PWM ratio, the output voltage will be: -

\$\dfrac{80}{255}\times (3.6 - 1.2) V = 0.753 V\$

So, without changing the PWM ratio, at light loads your motor is fed with 1.04 volts and as mechanical load increases this will drop to about 0.75 volts at 1A: -

[image]

It's not a good driver for your application really and it's worse if you use worst case (rather than typical) values.

Comment: But does this really justify the inversely proportionnal load and voltage? This sounds more like the minimum ajd maximum to "take into consideration" here, depending on other circumstances... but maybe I am wrong? Because if I test with the 1.5v alkaline battery it just stays 1.5v no matter what.

Comment: I can only say that there's been a few folk caught out with this problem.

Comment: So you're also saying that I should get another H-bridge? I thought this one was a popular one...

Comment: I don't think it's very suitable for your application unless you can live with the losses and stabilize with a control loop.

Comment: Hm, so I should rather build a custom circuit with diodes and transistors?

Comment: There are low volt-drop circuits around and most likely you need to look for ones with MOSFET output stages such as http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slvsba4&fileType=pdf - it has a combined on resistance of 0.33 ohms meaning, from a 5V supply you lose 0.33V at 1A. It's surface mount so DIP may suit you better but TI are probably the guys to search for the right part.

Comment: The other thing you can do is use an op-amp configured differentially to measure the actual dc volts. Feed it into an ADC input and adjust your PWM accordingly. Good luck. You'll get there with a bit of trial and error. It's never as easy as it first looks!!

Comment: I don't understand; can't I just feed it directly since it's 5v? The driver chip includes internal diodes for protection.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You said I should use an opamp to measure the actual dc voltage running through the motors right? Can't I just simply wire it in parallel to an arduino input pin then measure from there?

Comment: No, because the PWM is pulsing up and down and you need to measure directly across the motor (not to ground) or you won't precisely determine your actual motor voltage PLUS, the op-amp could be configured to smooth out the PWM leaving a simple ADC procedure in software. It's easier, I suspect to find an alternative part to the SN75441.

Comment: Ah... well I can't really afford to buy other components for this... but I'll take that into consideration for next time. I guess I can just set a pwm which produces 1.5v under typical load and hope that it doesn't burn under no load... Thank you very much!

Comment: Sometimes ya gotta take a risk!!!

Comment: Sorry for reopening this but even if PWM was pulsing up and down, can't I still measure the voltage because I already know that the PWM frequency that is constant?

Comment: The frequency may be constant, but the duty cycle isn't...

Comment: Why not? Isn't it always 80/255 in this case?

Comment: @user35485 You can measure the voltage across the motor but it needs to be done with a differential amplifier and a filter to convert the differential PWM signal to a 0V referenced signal then smoothed by a filter then measured (maybe using an ADC input). This gives you confidence in what precise voltage you are putting on the motor but that's all. In the big scheme, the motor mechanical load will change and this will slow down the motor hence, some folk would suggest using speed or positional feedback.

Comment: Alright, I'd need some extras components so finally I'll stick with this bit-risky design. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a lack of positional feedback.

The motors will run as expected in free air however as soon as they are mechanically loaded, then you need to know the position of the rotor so you can slow down the PWM and allow the shaft to turn.

Try reducing your switching frequency as the load increases. This will allow more power to be delivered to the windings for a longer period which should allow them to turn. Ideally, you need a feedback mechanism which will tell your processor the position of the rotor and whether to prolong the drive pulse in order to reach the next winding contact/brush point within the motor.

Secondly, there is a profound difference between a "H-Bridge Driver" and the actual "H-Bridge". The driver IC's task is solely to saturate the Base/Gate of a series of 4 Power MOSFETs/BJTs in a H-Configuration as illustrated here:

Attempting to drive the load directly from the driver IC may permanently damage it as it is not designed to do so.

Comment: Hm, I don't actually have the components for feedback (an encoder I guess). Is there another way around?

Answer (score 1):

You don't take into account the voltage drop that the output transistors introduce, it can be as high as 1.5v for the high side and 2v for the low side as the current increases (specified @1A).

You have calculated the PWM duty ratio to output a percentage of the input voltage but as the current requirement of the motor increased (when it gets loaded) there will be  an additional voltage drop (VCE drop) on the output transistors, plus I don't know if the 12v supply drops too.

Normally you need some kind of feedback to detect the output current and alter the duty of the PWM accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking of getting the voltage going to the motors with an Arduino digital pin... is that ok? I mean, should I worry about spikes or anything (this chip should include diodes afaik).

Comment: @user35485 A digital pin can't measure the voltage you'll need an analog pin. I don't think I would connect the voltage of the motor directly to an I/O pin, it's usually a good idea to add a buffer like an opamp.

Comment: doesn't it support up to 5.5v? Why would there be risks?

Comment: @user35485 The risks are because each time an inductor's supply is removed (i.e. at the PWM switching transitions), back-EMF is produced by the inductor with spikes that may well exceed the supply voltage. The coils of the motor are inductors. There's a strong possibility of fried Arduino.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh yeah but the driver includes flyback diodes.. so that should do it?